# Иерархический запрос Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Дана таблица.]
Нужно вывести строку показывающую иерархию начальник-подчинённый для рабочего с worker_id=6001004.
Результат должен выглядеть как строка:
PRODUCT MANAGER---AUTOMATION QA TEAM LEAD---AUTOMATION QA ENGINEER
Мой код выводит иерархию, но не знаю, как это сделать для рабочего с определённым id. И как сделать вывод в одной строке

```
    select 
      level, position
    from 
      job
    START WITH 
       position = 'PRODUCT MANAGER'
    CONNECT BY
        prior position_id = manager_id
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY
         position;
```

Comment: *не знаю, как это сделать для рабочего с определённым id* Наверное, добавить соответствующее условие в START WITH, не? *как сделать вывод в одной строке* GROUP BY + LISTAGG()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ. Вот он:

```
    select 
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(position, '-') as Path
    from 
    job
    WHERE worker_id=6001004
    START WITH 
    position = 'PRODUCT MANAGER'
    CONNECT BY
    prior position_id = manager_id
```